# BackgroundWorker Show Progress While Method Is Being Executed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a BackgroundWorker and Progressbar. On The DoWork event of the backgroundworker I'm executing a method that may take 2-5 seconds to complete but may take even longer sometimes. I want to show progress in the progressbar to indicate that something is still executing in the background. Most of the examples I found in the web are tasks from a loop but as I said my DoWork is executing a long running process and there's no way for me to determine the percentage of the progress. Please help. Here's my code.

```
 private  void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Shown += new EventHandler(MyForm_Shown);
        // To report progress from the background worker we need to set this property
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        // This event will be raised on the worker thread when the worker starts
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        // This event will be raised when we call ReportProgress
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;

    }

 private void MyForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Start the background worker
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();//this method may take 2-5 seconds to complete. I want to show progess in the progressbar while method execution is not yet finished.
    }

 private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The progress percentage is a property of e
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

 private void BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Perform something on complete
    }
```

Comment: if _"there's no way for me to determine the percentage"_, then maybe `progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee` ?

Comment: @vasily.sib I tried changing the backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged and I added progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee; I commented the // progressBar1.Value = e.Progressercentage; But still the same. The progressbar is still gray.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your `GetData()`. Try to replace it with `Thread.Sleep(5000);` for a test?

Comment: @vasily.sib still the same despite I changed it to  Thread.Sleep(5000);

Comment: I have just created a new WinForms project, droped `ProgressBar` and `BackgroundWorker` on form. Then set `progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee`, run `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();` on `Form1.Shown` event and run `Thread.Sleep(5000);` on `backgroundWorker1.DoWork` event. Everything is working as expected. `ProgressBar` shows indeterminate progress.

Comment: @vasily.sib I found the issue. The backgroundWorker1_ProgressChangedis not being fired. What I did is to add backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(10); in the DoWork event. Thanks for your help. progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee; is indeed the best choice.